# make the image load as quickly as possible when user hovers over the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know using sprites will fix this issue, is there some other better way?

Comment: I don't want to animate any element . Just want the image to load as quickly as possible when user hovers over the image

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.  But that would require javascript. It takes more time then sprites.

Comment: The other option is preloading, but that's one additional http request, so I'd use sprites instead.

Comment: @doniyor That would definitely **not** speed up the loading.

Comment: You could use [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) for background-images in your style sheet.

Comment: Even preloading is sometimes a bit unreliable (image pops in despite being preloaded). Sprites are the best solution if they are applicable. There are a lot of helpful tools out there to make it easier. Here's the first google result: http://wearekiss.com/spritepad

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers loads hover image until you hover on it. It is really noticeable if the image is large or traffic is slow.

Ideally, you want to use **Sprites image**, and position them when you hover.

Like this http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b

**Pre-load images** to dummy div like this -

```
#temp
{
    background-image: url(/images/image1.png);
    background-image: url(/images/image2.png);
    background-image: url(/images/image3.png);
}
```

Comment: How about adding image on html page and display it none . And with javascript change image on hover ?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the image  to be changed on html page and display it none  with inline css so that it gets loaded when the html page is rendered, and with javascript change image on hover.